# How to get the categories of custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type. In that post type the taxonomy is category and I have to display the all the categories of the custom post type i.e. project.

I want to like option list.

My custom post type is "Project".

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20574/how-to-get-all-taxonomies-of-a-post-type

Comment: `get_categories('taxonomy=category&type=project');` - not worthy of being an answer

Comment: @user3747821 please respond if solution is working on your end

Answer (score 0):

In actual custom post types are same as normal posts in WordPress. The only difference is there isn't any in-built WordPress functions to get the information you need, but you can get it by using the `wp_query` class. This offers a nice way to access all the information in your WordPress database.

To get the custom post type categories you need to change the arguments passed into the `wp_list_categories` function.

You need to define the taxonomy argument.

If you have a custom post type for your products then to display all the categories for products you need to use the following snippet.

```
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('products');

if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
{
 foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
 {
     $args = array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'show_count' => 0,
          'pad_counts' => 0,
          'hierarchical' => 1,
          'taxonomy' => $tax,
          'title_li' => ''
        );

     wp_list_categories( $args );
 }
}
```